# Why am I getting weird shadows on my Donut?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting, shadows

I get weird shadows. It was worse before, but I went into sculpt and smoothed the surfaces out, but these ones will not go away D:
Btw this is only a problem in Cycles, but no Eevee
[image: Weird Shadows]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Looks like there are holes in your icing mesh or the icing mesh is overlapping itself or the donut mesh.  Maybe add your blend file to your question?  ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))